# onSearchRequested() result in same activity

Tags: android

i have implement in my application the search method onSearchRequested() via list  and it work well  and  i create  2  activity one for list data  and another for the search result 
in that form

public class acitvity1 extends InterfaceBase {

```
    @Override
    ListAdapter makeMeAnAdapter(Intent intent) {

          return(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));

    }       
}
```

and  the activity 2 who include  the search result

```
public abstract class Acitvity2 extends InterfaceBase {

   @Override
    ListAdapter makeMeAnAdapter(Intent intent) {

            ListAdapter adapter=null;

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
                    String query=intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                    List<String> results=searchItems(query);

                    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results);
                    setTitle("Search : "+query);
            }
            return(adapter);
    }  
    private List<String> searchItems(String query) {
            SearchSuggestionProvider
                    .getBridge(this)
                    .saveRecentQuery(query, null);

            List<String> results=new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String item : items) {
                    if (item.indexOf(query)>-1) {
                            results.add(item);
                    }
            }
            return(results);
    }
```

so its there  a possible to make the search result appear in callback activity mean in the activity1 and is there any change should do in the manifest file too 
thx for help

Comment: if i want put the activity1 in tabhost and  make  the result in the activity2 appear in the  same  tab its is possible >? itred   with tabgroupactivity but it didnt work any help with that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onNewIntent like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    makeMeAnAdapter(intent);
}
```

Then include the search metadata in activity2, something like:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/search" />
```

Comment: its not solved  its return empty activity but if i add tab to the activity1 by 
 intent = new Intent().setClass(this, activity1.class);
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");

spec.setIndicator("tab1");
 spec.setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);
its possible to make the second activity appear in the tab1